# Specify python package dependency with different extras for different versions

Tags: python, pip, dependencies

I have a dependency on the rdflib package. It specifies, only for 5.0.0, a 'sparql' extra that is needed for my package to work correctly. I want to specify that I work with rdflib >=4, rdflib[sparql] only for 5.0.0, or rdflib >=6. Is there a way to specify this? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#complete-grammar suggests not and

rdflib[sparql]>=4

means I require [sparql] which means only 5.0.0 can be installed *correctly*. pip will go ahead and install rdflib 6.0.1 with a warning but then pkg_resources will fail loading entry points in rdflib because it actually checks for extras at runtime. There's no other place to specify extras.

Comment: Well, I tried the install again and found that rdflib 6.0.1 will be installed, but with a warning: `WARNING: rdflib 6.0.1 does not provide the extra 'sparql'`

Comment: Then I found out even though later versions of rdflib will install, they don't work as intended, so I'd still like a way to specify what's actually intended...